# Not getting value from instamojo API

Tags: ios, swift, payment, instamojo

I got null value from API
https://sample-sdk-server.instamojo.com/status?" + values from this url when callback from instamojo payment gateway screen

I passed `env` and `transactionId` in query string in above url and I got result like `["payment_id": , "amount": , "status": ]`

So give me any solution for the same

Is is right to pass `sample-sdk-server` in url  ??

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem, after some research I got this

Use this API for getting payment response

> https://test.instamojo.com/v2/gateway/orders/transaction_id:yourTransectionID/

and pass access token you get as header Bearer token like below

```
let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.accessToken,
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    ]
```